# Why can't I compute the integral with the following method?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I understand the following solution, where we multiply the integral by $2/2$ so we can make use of the standard form to solve it.
$$\int \frac{e^x}{2e^x-1} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}2 \int \frac{2e^x}{2e^x-1} \, dx = \frac {1}2  \ln|2e^x-1|+C$$
However, I tried doing this integral with another method where I took out the constant and used the standard form to integrate, but it does not work. Why?
$$\int \frac{e^x}{2e^x-1} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int \frac{e^x}{2(e^x-\frac{1}2)} \, dx = \frac {1}2 \int \frac{e^x}{e^x-\frac{1}2} = \frac {1}2  \ln \left|e^x-\frac{1}2 \right| +C$$

Comment: Ah, you've discovered why "plus C" can be tough for new students. Take derivatives of your results and see what happens.

Comment: They both are same. Take lcm inside $ln$ in second result and then use $lna/b = lna - lnb$ and so $c- ln2$ will become a new constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answers are equivalent:

$$\frac 1 2 \ln |2 e^x - 1| = \frac 1 2 \left( \ln(2) + \ln \left| e^x - \frac 12 \right| \right)$$

The two indefinite integrals differ by a constant (namely, $\ln(2)/2$), and hence everything is fine. You may think of it as being the case that

$$
\begin{align*}
&\int \frac{e^x}{2e^x-1} \, \mathrm{d}x  = \frac {1}2  \ln|2e^x-1|+C \\
&\int \frac{e^x}{2e^x-1} \, \mathrm{d}x   = \frac {1}2  \ln \left|e^x-\frac{1}2 \right| +D
\end{align*}$$

where $C,D$ are constants of integration, and $D = C + \ln(2)/2$ (still a constant, but just a shifted one).

You can verify this by differentiation as well.

Bear in mind what's going on here: any two antiderivatives of a function differ by a constant, as a consequence of the mean value theorem. Thus, when you write "$F(x)+C$" for an integral, you're not saying that any one function $F$ is an antiderivative, but rather any function that differs from $F$ by a constant is an antiderivative.